# Please resolve the syntax error in the mysql insert query

Tags: mysql, sql, debugging

I am using mysql 5.5.27

At places where it looks like double quotes are two single quotes closer together, and they are actually null values in the excel sheetin the db.

I get the following error,

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLS… You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
  check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
  syntax to use near 'CASE,lname,fname,gender,dob,ssn,… at line 1
```

the actual query is

```
Insert into 
  work(CASE,lname,fname,gender,dob
```

Comment: The original query you've posted is incomplete and should be formatted better. It will help those that are trying to answer to decipher where the problem is (or test locally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"CASE" is a reserved word : See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

You may escape it :

```
Insert into child(`CASE`,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,GENDER,DOB… American','1689 Crucible Street','','Pittsburgh','PA','15210','(4…
```

But I would personally prefer renaming the column.

Comment: So if a column consists of date data you would rather not name it `date`? If the column actually holds 'case' data (whatever that may be) I'd strongly advise to name it that way, rather than renaming a column to something else just because the original (and fitting) name is a reserved word. To enable us to use reserved words in names, that's what the backticks are for ...

Comment: Usually, supposing you're just not making a homework 2 pages PHP site, you have to manage your base, and to use many tools for that, you have to explore your base using command line queries, etc.. Having reserved words as columns **isn't** recommended as it fast get painful.

Comment: Thank you very much. People like you save our time and increase your knowledge. Keep helping others by solving their bugs.

Answer (score 0):

CASE is a reserved word ... quote it ..

Answer (score 0):

For mysql:

```
insert into tableName values()
```

Anyway you have SQL syntax errors:

Insert into child(CASE,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,GENDER,DOB… American','1689 Crucible Street','','Pittsburgh','PA','15210','(4…

1. Case is a reserwed word: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html
2. In **DOB… American'**  you miss a **'** (*'DOB… American'*)